# Dimension of an algebraic variety

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

I would like to compute, using Groebner bases, the dimension of the variety defined by a set of polynomials in several variables. In the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety#Computation_of_the_dimension) the method is described, and an implementation is possible, but I was hoping there was a predefined function that would do that.

Comment: Is this about math or *Mathematica*?

Comment: Dear Yves, this was a question about Mathematica, I wanted to know if there is any predefined function that computes the dimension by implementing the algorithm cited above.

Comment: Thank you for the info - in that case you are in good hands with Daniel :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I show some aged code cribbed from [this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jul/msg00150.html) (See also [this library item](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7523/)). There is some amount of explanation in each. But the most salient quote, from the post, is this. "It is unlikely that I can do justice to the explanation. So far as correctness goes, let's just say the code is on the honor system."

```
firstContainsSecond[l1_, l2_] := (Union[l1, l2] === l1)

isIndependentSet[set_, sets_] := 
 Map[! firstContainsSecond[set, #] &, sets]

getMaxIndependentSets[vars_, inset_, heds_, maxlen_, indx_, sets_] := 
 Module[{currentset, vlen = Length[vars], ilen = Length[inset], 
   enlarged = False, newmax = maxlen, maxsets = sets}, 
  Do[If[ilen + vlen - i + 1 <= maxlen, Break[]];
   currentset = Append[inset, vars[[i]]];
   If[isIndependentSet[currentset, 
     heds], {maxsets, enlarged, newmax} = 
     getMaxIndependentSets[vars, currentset, heds, newmax, i + 1, 
      maxsets];
    If[! enlarged, maxsets = {maxsets, currentset};
     newmax = Max[newmax, Length[currentset]];
     enlarged = True;];], {i, indx, vlen}];
  {maxsets, enlarged, newmax}]

idealDimension[ideal_, vars_] := 
 Module[{ord = MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic, gb, 
   pheads, heds, maxsets, el, mlen}, 
  gb = GroebnerBasis[ideal, vars, ord];
  pheads = 
   Map[First[First[#]] &, 
    First[Internal`DistributedTermsList[gb, vars, ord]]];
  heds = Apply[
    And, (Map[(vars*#) &, (pheads /. _?Positive -> 1)]/.0 -> 
      Sequence[])];
  {maxsets, el, mlen} = 
   getMaxIndependentSets[vars, {}, heds, 0, 1, {}];
  mlen]
```

This comes with no warranties. If ever there were any, they must have expired by now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! I will try the code and let you know how it worked ;)

Comment: Daniel, I managed to get the code working in Mathematica 9, I will post it here in a couple of days after some debugging. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code kindly provided by Daniel Lichtblau in the accepted answer, modified to work with *Mathematica 9*. All the credit goes to him, and, of course, this comes with no warranties ;) The code is inspired from T.Becker, V.Weisphenning - [Groebner bases](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0913-3), (Table 9.6, pp 449).

```
firstContainsSecond[l1_, l2_] := (Union[l1, l2] === l1);
isIndependentSet[set_, sets_] := 
  Map[! firstContainsSecond[set, #] &, sets];
getMaxIndependentSets[vars_, inset_, heds_, maxlen_, indx_, sets_] := 
  Module[{currentset, vlen = Length[vars], ilen = Length[inset], 
    enlarged = False, newmax = maxlen, maxsets = sets},
   Do[
    If[ilen + vlen - i + 1 <= maxlen, Break[]];
    currentset = Append[inset, vars[[i]]];
    If[And @@ 
      isIndependentSet[currentset, heds], {maxsets, enlarged, 
       newmax} = 
      getMaxIndependentSets[vars, currentset, heds, newmax, i + 1, 
       maxsets];
     If[! enlarged, maxsets = Append[maxsets, currentset];
      newmax = Max[newmax, Length[currentset]];
      enlarged = True;];], {i, indx, vlen}];
   {maxsets, enlarged, newmax}
   ];
idealDimension[ideal_, vars_] := 
  Module[{ord = DegreeReverseLexicographic, gb, pheads, heds, maxsets,
     el, mlen}, 
   gb = GroebnerBasis[ideal, vars, MonomialOrder -> ord];
   pheads = Map[First[MonomialList[#, vars, ord]] &, gb];
   heds = Map[Variables[#] &, pheads];
   {maxsets, el, mlen} = 
    getMaxIndependentSets[vars, {}, heds, 0, 1, {}];
   mlen
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about the context change to `DistributedTermsList`. And the "new" `MonomialList` did not exist when I wrote that. Ironically, version 3 also had a `MonomialList` that was related to the current one. I no longer recall what internal misgivings caused it to go away, only to reappear a few versions later.

Comment: Why does the result depend on the order of variables? e. g. `idealDimension[{-1 + a^2 + b^2 + d^2 + e^2, b d - a e + c e - b f,  a b + b c + d e + e f, -1 + b^2 + c^2 + e^2 + f^2} , {a, b, c, d, e, f}]` gives 3 but with the reversed order `{f, e, d, c, b, a}` the result is 4.